# Calculating annual return of stocks with Google finance data

Tags: google-sheets

Below formula returns Annual Return for the year 2016

=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",date(2016,12,31)),2,2)/INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",date(2016,1,1)),2,2)-1

This works fine for most stocks including GOOG, however it returns the below error for some stocks -

**Error
Function INDEX parameter 2 value is 2. Valid values are between 0 and 1 inclusive.**

Any guidance will be helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: NSE: BIOCON for example...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the date. 1/1 is New Year's Day, and the markets are closed, therefore the stock price on that day is returning #N/A, which doesn't have an index 2,2.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if you use `GOOGLEFINANCE` with a date the market was closed the formula returns `#N/A`. In your example both 2016/12/31 and 2016/1/1 were dates when the market was closed.

The only way I've been able to solve it so far is by using `GOOGLEFINANCE` to return prices in a range around the specified date and then use `QUERY` to return the last one prior to the specified date like this:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","Close",DATE(2016,12,31)-5,6),"select Col2 where Col1 <= date '2015-01-01' order by Col1 desc limit 1",False)
```

So to get the annual return for GOOG on 2016, enter **GOOG** on cell G3 and **2016** in cell G2 and use:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(G3,"Close",DATE(G2,12,31)-5,6),"select Col2 where Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(DATE(G2,12,31), "YYYY-MM-DD")&"' order by Col1 desc limit 1",False)/QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(G3,"Close",DATE(G2,1,1)-5,6),"select Col2 where Col1 < date '"&TEXT(DATE(G2,1,1), "YYYY-MM-DD")&"' order by Col1 desc limit 1",False)-1
```

See this [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MeFqwmDMRXdg8ZcpLqVAFInOQ8b-6nA7Bk8uPnmj4RA/edit?usp=sharing) for more clarity and also this other [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115168/how-to-get-close-price-for-last-date-market-was-open) here in Stack Exchange in case someone comes up with a better solution as this is remarkably long for something that should be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put `GOOG` into A1 and `BIOCON` into A2 then:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"price",date(2016,12,31)),2,2)/INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,"price",date(2016,1,1)),2,2)-1
```

somewhere and copy it down one row (in the same column) it should work.

Comment: Tanks. I tried but it still throws the same error for NSE:BIOCON.

Comment: I just copied the formula to a new sheet and yes it does work. The original sheet contains > 1000 google finance formulas and probably Google limits it in some way.

Comment: Also throws the same error with GOOG